# Deploy to serverless Azure Functions Failed

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to deploy Azure Functions in already created App Service in Azure portal.

Using `sls deploy` CLI for deploying my Azure function, but while deploying the functions `sls` is trying to create new resource group for which I don't have access.

Following is the output of `sls deploy` command:

```
$ sls deploy
Serverless: Removing .serverless directory
Serverless: Parsing Azure Functions Bindings.json...
Serverless: Building binding for function: admin event: httpTrigger
Serverless: Parsing Azure Functions Bindings.json...
Serverless: Building binding for function: image event: httpTrigger
Serverless: Parsing Azure Functions Bindings.json...
Serverless: Building binding for function: report event: httpTrigger
Serverless: Parsing Azure Functions Bindings.json...
Serverless: Building binding for function: gaims event: httpTrigger
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Logging into Azure
Serverless: Using subscription ID: <SUBSCRIPTION_ID>
Serverless: Creating resource group: <ALREADY_CREATED_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: The client '<USER_NAME>' with object id '<OBJECT_ID>' does not have authorization to perform action 
     'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope 
    '/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourcegroups/ALREADY_CREATED_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME' or the scope is invalid. 
    If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
      at new RestError (C:\Users\analysis-node\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\lib\restError.ts:18:5)
      at C:\Users\analysis-node\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\lib\policies\deserializationPolicy.ts:117:27
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              10.20.1
     Framework Version:         1.71.1
     Plugin Version:            3.6.12
     SDK Version:               2.3.0
     Components Version:        2.30.11
```

In `serverless.yml`, I've also specified the `resourceGroup` parameter. Here is the gist of `serverless.yml`

```
provider:
  stage: dev
  name: azure
  region: East US 2
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  resourceGroup: <ALREADY_CREATED_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>
  subscriptionId: <SUBSCRIPTION_ID>
```

Is there any way to set *resource group* in `serverless` cli which can be used while deploying the functions?

Comment: From the error message, looks like the service principal / user trying to execute this doesn't have permission to create resources, isn't it? Probably should be a contributor. there is a similar question here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37689720/5344880] with accepted answer. hope it helps

Comment: Not looking to create a resource group. Only want to deploy my functions under an App Service.

Comment: @ParagJadhav I agree with Guru, you should check the subscription permission of the service principal or user you used to deploy the function.

Comment: @TonyJu I have a contributor access to the function that I'm sure of. I can even deploy the function in the current app service if I generate a new project template using Azure Function extension in VS Code. Please let me know if you want me to update the question with more granularity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to deploy the Azure functions by breaking down the deployment in two parts

1. Package the project using [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/guide/packaging/).

   ```
   sls package
   ```
2. Deploy the packaged zip file using [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-deployment-source-config-local-git).

   ```
   az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g {RESOURCE_GROUP} -n {APP_SERVICE_NAME} --src .serverless/project-zip.zip
   ```

Hope this helps someone who is facing the same issue.

Edit:

Looks like this issue might get resolved in upcoming releases.

Link: https://github.com/serverless/serverless-azure-functions/issues/469